# Query to AS400 from a dataset

Tags: c#, dataset, ibm-midrange

I have a dataset and my question is how can I read a specific value and set in a query to delete.

For example the query I would send to the AS400:

> delete from xxx.yyy where data1 = dataset.tables[0].value

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is close.  You are grabbing the first table but not the row & then column value in that row.  You can do this several ways.

Here's a few samples:

```
datasetname.tables[0].Rows[0].Item(0) 

datasetname.tables[0].Rows[0].Item("ColumnName") 

datasetname.tables[0].Rows[0][0] 

datasetname.tables[0].Rows[0]["ColumnName"]
```

Depending on what you are setting against you might need to convert/cast or use the ToString on your value.

Comment: Cool thanks for the help, sadly I can't use a store procedure this time.

Comment: @Enrique - What do you mean you can't use a stored procedure?  The above code is using a dataset as explained in your question?

Comment: Oh I mean it would be easier to solve it with a sp, but for this program in specific I can't use them.

Your solution is perfect, sorry to confuse you.